# Python: Getting Traceback error while executing the code

Tags: python, elementtree, taurus

When I run the code as `bzt test.yml` I am getting the error.
Before it was working fine.

```
C:\etc\tmp\my-test>more test.yml
---
execution:
   concurrency: 50
   hold-for: 2m30s
   ramp-up: 1m
   scenario:
      requests:
         - url: http://server12:12012/

    C:\etc\tmp\my-test>bzt test.yml
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Python27\Scripts\bzt-script.py", line 9, in <module>
            load_entry_point('bzt==1.6.7', 'console_scripts', 'bzt')()
          File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 564, in load_entry_point
            return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
          File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2621, in load_entry_point
            return ep.load()
          File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2281, in load
            return self.resolve()
          File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2287, in resolve
            module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
          File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\bzt\cli.py", line 32, in <module>
            from bzt.engine import Engine, Configuration, ScenarioExecutor
          File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\bzt\engine.py", line 37, in <module>
            from bzt.six import build_opener, install_opener, urlopen, request, numeric_types, iteritems
          File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\bzt\six\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
            import elementtree.ElementTree as etree
        ImportError: No module named elementtree.ElementTree
```

Comment: Please share code in bzt-script.py.

Comment: Hello @DineshPundkar here is the code: ` #!c:\python27\python.exe
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'bzt==1.6.7','console_scripts','bzt'
__requires__ = 'bzt==1.6.7'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('bzt==1.6.7', 'console_scripts', 'bzt')()
    ) `

Comment: It is better to add your code to the question, where formatting can be applied to it.

Comment: Try uninstalling bzt module by - pip uninstall bzt. Then install it - pip install bzt.

Comment: I tried doing it but it's been failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like missing or corrupt [lxml](http://lxml.de/) package to me.

Workarounds are in:

1. Try out [Taurus Installer](http://gettaurus.org/msi/)
2. Reinstall `lxml` and/or `bzt` packages via pip.

Check out:

- [Taurus -> Installing and Upgrading -> Windows](http://gettaurus.org/install/Installation/#Windows)
- [Taurus: A New Star in the Test Automation Tools Constellation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation)

  for detailed setup instructions.

If the problem persists update your question with the *bzt.log* file contents.

Comment: Hello @Dmitri T i have reinstall and updated both bzt and lmxl but still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
ImportError: No module named elementtree.ElementTree
```

Are you sure it shouldn't be

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
```

Otherwise check if you have this dependency installed or if you have a **"elementtree" folder** in your current project that screws with the import lookup.

Comment: I don't have any element folder. So please tell me any other solution for it.